# Select columns with many observations

Tags: r

I have a dataset with lots of observations and lots of variables. But some variables only have real values for a few observations. How can I delete variables that have less than, say, 500 observations?

I've been trying to figure out a way to do this in the context of `dplyr`, but `select()` doesn't seem to work that way.

This doesn't quite make sense either, but it's the direction I've been thinking:

```
dat[,sum(!is.na) > 500]
```

Comment: Count number of `NA`?

Comment: Try subsetting like `dat[, colSums(!is.na(dat)) > 500]` maybe

Comment: @Frank That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `vapply`

```
dat[vapply(dat, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) <=500, 0)]
```

Or with `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(is.na(x)) <= 500, dat)
```